# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when using FirebaseOptions.Builder to connect java to firebase

Tags: java, maven, firebase

I have downloaded all the firebase maven dependencies jar files (that we get when using groupID com.google.firebase with artifactID firebase-admin, with version 6.2.0) into a dynamic web project.
I then used the code given in firebase documentation for Java to connect to firebase. Here is the documentation code:

```
public class FirebaseUpdater {

public static void main(String[] args){
    FileInputStream serviceAccount;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new 
                FileInputStream("C:/Users/Asus/workspace/"
                        + "school1/schoolbackup_service.json");
        //FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://schoolbackup-f2429.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("restricted_access/secret_document");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(document);
          }

          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          }
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

However, I get the following error for the function FirebaseOptions.Builder:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getFromServiceLoader(OAuth2Credentials.java:291)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.<init>(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:165)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:266)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:195)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:160)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
at FirebaseUpdater.main(FirebaseUpdater.java:25)
```

Here is the folder that contains the list of my dependencies for com.google.firebase. They have all been added to my reference libraries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3zox.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBMSS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoSPs.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is it some missing jar? Should the jars not be in the reference libraries? Should I not use maven dependencies for a dynamic web project? Or is it that I cannot even use firebase connectivity in non-gradle and non-maven projects? And what is the workaround for this problem? Because I am in desperate need of Java-Firebase connectivity.

Please help!!! Thank you in advance

Comment: **google-auth-library-java** is getting a different version of **Guava** then it was compiled with.

Comment: So what do i do sir? These are the dependencies I automatically got when I used a maven project to extract the java-firebase dependencies.